# Select rows where related rows only have unmatched years

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

I have a `PROJECTS` table and a `PROJECT_FINANCES` table:

```
with 
projects (project_id, year_construction) as (
select 1, 2022 from dual union all
select 2, 2023 from dual union all
select 3, 2024 from dual union all
select 4, 2025 from dual
),
project_finances (project_id, year_funding) as (
select 1, 2022 from dual union all
select 2, 2022 from dual union all
select 2, 2023 from dual union all
select 3, 2025 from dual
)
select
    *
from
    projects
```

```
PROJECTS:

PROJECT_ID YEAR_CONSTRUCTION
---------- -----------------
         1              2022
         2              2023
         3              2024
         4              2025
```

```
PROJECT_FINANCES:

PROJECT_ID YEAR_FUNDING
---------- ------------
         1         2022

         2         2022
         2         2023

         3         2025
```

I want to select `PROJECTS` where the related rows in `PROJECT_FINANCES` only have years that don't match the parent project year.

For example, `PROJECT 3; 2024` has a related project finance record `PROJECT 3; 2025`. So, there ***are*** related rows, but none of those rows' years match the year of the parent project. So I want to select that project.

I don't want to select `PROJECT 4`, since it doesn't have any related rows.

The result would look like this:

```
PROJECT_ID YEAR_CONSTRUCTION
---------- -----------------
         3              2024
```

---

How can I do that using Oracle 18c SQL?

Edit: My priority is conciseness; I'm not too worried about performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` and, within the sub-query, aggregate and use a `HAVING` clause and conditional aggregation to check the corresponding year does not exist:

```sql
select *
from   projects p
WHERE  EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM   project_finances f
  GROUP BY f.project_id
  HAVING COUNT(CASE f.year_funding WHEN p.year_construction THEN 1 END) = 0
  AND    p.project_id = f.project_id
)
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | PROJECT_ID | YEAR_CONSTRUCTION |
> | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 2024 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f92171935bd6c1084200d2370518b3d7)*

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables and use aggregation with the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT p.project_id, p.year_construction
FROM projects p INNER JOIN project_finances f
ON f.project_id = p.project_id
GROUP BY p.project_id, p.year_construction
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN p.year_construction = f.year_funding THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ff6ea7d0b2e470fa98f62d20b6586040).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for CTEs!

---

How about

- JOIN, which will fetch only matching projects, and then
- MINUS set operator to find which matching projects don't have matching years?

---

```
SQL> with
  2  projects (project_id, year_construction) as (
  3  select 1, 2022 from dual union all
  4  select 2, 2023 from dual union all
  5  select 3, 2024 from dual union all
  6  select 4, 2025 from dual
  7  ),
  8  project_finances (project_id, year_funding) as (
  9  select 1, 2022 from dual union all
 10  select 2, 2022 from dual union all
 11  select 2, 2023 from dual union all
 12  select 3, 2025 from dual
 13  )
 14  select a.*
 15  from projects a join project_finances b on a.project_id = b.project_id
 16  minus
 17  select * from project_finances;

PROJECT_ID YEAR_CONSTRUCTION
---------- -----------------
         3              2024

SQL>
```

---

It would be even simpler if you'd want to get `project_id = 4` because - technically speaking - it really doesn't have matching year (nor ID) in `project_finances`.

```
 14  select * from projects
 15  minus
 16  select * from project_finances;

PROJECT_ID YEAR_CONSTRUCTION
---------- -----------------
         3              2024
         4              2025

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet, there's another method to use;

to outer(*left*) join the tables by respective year columns, and then to filter by *null* valued year columns of the second one such as

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM projects p
  LEFT JOIN project_finances pf
    ON pf.year_funding = p.year_construction
 WHERE pf.year_funding IS NULL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9de3b751fbaab1bf82d54eeb679a76a6)</kbd>